# How to make a batch upgrade system for an rpg game

Tags: batch-file

I am making a batch rpg game, and am working on a shop. You are supposed to be able to upgrade your weapons/armor, and i would like to know how to make a way so the price increases when you buy. Heres what i have:

```
if %money% GEQ (%WeaponLevel% * 4) / 2 then set money=(%WeaponLevel% * 4) / 2 & set WeaponLevel=%WeaponLevel% + 1
```

Thanks! Hope i'm not **too** far off :)

Comment: You can't do math inside of `if` conditions. You need to set a variable to the value you want, then check it against that.

Comment: Also, `then` isn't a batch keyword.

Comment: Oh i knew the "then" thing, that was a typo :) thx though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
set /a $=money - (weaponlevel *2)
if %$% geq 0 set /a money=$&set /a weaponlevel +=1
```

Using a temporary variable `$` (its name is not relevant - but don't use the reserved names `temp` or `tmp`),

- set the tempval to money-(weaponlevel*2)

Note that in set/a, the variablenames do not need to be enclosed in `%`. Also that ((%weaponlevel% * 4) / 2) is exactly the same as (weaponlevel*2)

- if the resultant temporary value is greater than or equal to zero, then change the values of `money` and `weaponlevel` using `set /a`; the new value of `money` is in the temporary variable and `+=1` increments a value.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
rem My weapon upgrade script
set price=weaponlevel * 4
set /a money-= %price%
```

Run that script whenever the player goes to upgrade the weapon and the price will be equal to the weapon level * 4 everytime and will reduce the money by that set price. I hope this help : D